# Symlinked Movies and Downloads. Restore icons?

Tags: macos, ssd, symlink

I've recently replaced the optical drive of my Macbook Pro with an SSD and installed Mountain Lion freshly on there. This leaves the HDD available as well and on by popular suggestion I've symlinked a couple directories. iTunes Media, Movies and Downloads, specifically. Worked fine!

Now I've ran into a slight inconvenience: the icons and folder name localizations got messed up. Have a look at the screenshot below.

[image]

My system is set up to be Dutch, but as you can see in the screenshot above the Downloads and Movies folders are still English. I did add .localized files to both folders and the actual folders on the HDD did change to localized names (their icons did not change, but then again they're not in a Users directory - only the simlink is).

The icons are missing in the Finder side-bar as well, as you can see.

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: You did the HDD/SDD setup wrong. Normally, missing localisation is not a problem. Will investigate.

Comment: What steps am I supposed to take? I installed 10.8 on the SSD, then I rm'd Movies, created a folder called Movies on the HDD and then I  created a link (`ln -s /Volumes/HDD/Movies ~/Movies`) and added a localization file (`touch /Volumes/HDD/Movies/.localized`)

Comment: Why did you choose to keep the volumes separate, rather then joining them together into a "fusion drive"?

Comment: I was not aware of the fact that I could join them together in a Fusion drive. I assume I have to re-install my system entirely if I'd want to switch to that now, right? Are there any other major advantages? It seems to just make things a bit less transparant..

Comment: Setting up a HDD/SDD combo has been properly explained on Ask Different. Search for it. And yes, you would have to reinstall to create a Fusion Drive. That too, has been explained. Search and you will be enlightened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the same for the applications folder, and the way to get the icon was to copy/paste the original icon to the (new) original folder, the symlink *regained* the icon automatically and instantly.

The name of the symLink can be edited without problem, if it needs to be in the translated version, just translate the symLinked folder.

Comment: The icon trick fixed the Finder icons, thanks (upvoted)! For some reason the navigation bar is not picking up on it though, which is reasonable given the fact that it's changing the appearance rather than making OSX recognise it as a system folder.

I realise I can edit the name manually, but then it's also translated when I approach it via command line or through other apps that are looking for the default folders. The OS then also creates a new ~/Movies folder on reboot.